# iOS giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS for my function

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I wrote a small function to zoom by 2x. But it is giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while I run it. Below is the code

```
- (CGImageRef)CGImageScale2x:(CGImageRef)imgRef
{
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
    CGRect scaledRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(imgRect, transform);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                   scaledRect.size.width,
                                                   scaledRect.size.height,
                                                   8,
                                                   0,
                                                   colorSpace,
                                                   kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(bmContext, FALSE);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bmContext, kCGInterpolationNone);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextScaleCTM(bmContext, 2.0, 2.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                             scaledRect.size.width,
                                             scaledRect.size.height),
                       imgRef);

    CGImageRef scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmContext);
    CFRelease(bmContext);
    [(id)scaledImage autorelease];

    return scaledImage;
}
```

I am new to iOS. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Well for one thing, you are saying "My context has zero bytes per row" by passing 0 as the fifth argument of `CGBitmapContextCreate` and for another you can't autorelease CG objects.  Don't try.

Comment: @borrrden Hi, I am modifying an already working function to rotate the image to do my zooming. In that function fifth argument of  CGBitmapContextCreate is zero and also autorelease is called for CGImageRef object. That function is working fine. So I doubt if that is the bug. Please comment

Comment: Autorelease is an objective-c function, but CGImageRef is a C object so autorelease does not apply to it (and neither does release which is eventually called by the autorelease pool).  It would also be helpful to know which line is causing the crash as well.  As far as the zero thing, perhaps Apple has stopped using it in the backend because they realize they can calculate it but it's strange to have zero there.

Comment: @borrrden Taking your advice I commented the auto release and now the crash is not happening. I am calling CGImageRelease later on the return value. It is working but is it correct? Thanks :)

Comment: You are responsible for releasing it later.

Comment: @borrrden Thank you. I am not able to accept your answer as the right answer. I cannot that option next to your answer. Actually I am writing this function to zoom preview frames from the camera. Instead of doing this, is there a way to use the built-in digital zoom of the camera like in Android (setZoom() method) ?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGImageRef` can't be autoreleased, it's Core Foundation type. Try to use `CGImageRelease(scaledImage)` instead.

Comment: Should be `CGImageRelease` but then again there might not be a difference other than naming.